# How does pandas groupby transform work internally?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am a bit confused about the internal workings of pandas groupby transform functionality.
I will use the following example to explain the areas of confusion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     "group": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
     "name": ["A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "A3", "B3", "C3"],
     "score": [97, 93, 92, 94, 95, 93, 100, 92, 93],
    "p": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 })
df.index=[3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
```

```
g = df.groupby('group')
```

Confusions: How the Data actually gets iterated over and how does transform decide the columns on which to apply the transformation?

- If I do no operations and pass just a print function to the transform, then the iteration is first over the columns of the first group one by one, then it passes the entire first group, then it is over the columns in the second group one by one and then the entire second group and so on:

```
g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x,'*'*20))
prints that show up:
 3    A1
5    B1
7    C1
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 3    97
5    93
7    92
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 3    1
5    2
7    3
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


   name  score  p
3   A1     97  1
5   B1     93  2
7   C1     92  3 ********************


 9     A2
11    B2
13    C2
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 9     94
11    95
13    93
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 9     4
11    5
13    6
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


    name  score  p
9    A2     94  4
11   B2     95  5
13   C2     93  6 ********************


 15    A3
17    B3
19    C3
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 15    100
17     92
19     93
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 15    7
17    8
19    9
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


    name  score  p
15   A3    100  7
17   B3     92  8
19   C3     93  9 ********************
```

- If I make any operations in the transform function that can be applied to both the object types and the numeric types, then the iteration behaviour persists. Each column in the 1st group, the entire first group, each column in the second group, the second group and so on.

```
g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x*2,'*'*20))
3    A1A1
5    B1B1
7    C1C1
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 3    194
5    186
7    184
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 3    2
5    4
7    6
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


    name  score  p
3  A1A1    194  2
5  B1B1    186  4
7  C1C1    184  6 ********************


 9     A2A2
11    B2B2
13    C2C2
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 9     188
11    190
13    186
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 9      8
11    10
13    12
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


     name  score   p
9   A2A2    188   8
11  B2B2    190  10
13  C2C2    186  12 ********************


 15    A3A3
17    B3B3
19    C3C3
Name: name, dtype: object ********************


 15    200
17    184
19    186
Name: score, dtype: int64 ********************


 15    14
17    16
19    18
Name: p, dtype: int64 ********************


     name  score   p
15  A3A3    200  14
17  B3B3    184  16
19  C3C3    186  18 ********************
```

- However, if I make any numeric-only computations in the transform function, then the entire group after each column iteration is not iterated over. The order of iteration is also changed. It is all the groups in the first columns, then all the groups in the second columns, then the third column and so on and so forth. Earlier it was the first group of the first column, then the first group of the second column etc and then move similarly to the next group after exhausting all the columns in the first group. Transform is also smart enough to understand that it is a numeric computation and to handle the object typed columns gracefully without throwing errors. It simply skips the object typed columns:

```
g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x-x.mean(),'\n',x,'*'*20))
prints that show up:

 3    3.0
5   -1.0
7   -2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64 
 3    97
5    93
7    92
Name: a, dtype: int64 ********************


 9     0.0
11    1.0
13   -1.0
Name: b, dtype: float64 
 9     94
11    95
13    93
Name: b, dtype: int64 ********************


 15    5.0
17   -3.0
19   -2.0
Name: c, dtype: float64 
 15    100
17     92
19     93
Name: c, dtype: int64 ********************


 3   -1.0
5    0.0
7    1.0
Name: a, dtype: float64 
 3    1
5    2
7    3
Name: a, dtype: int64 ********************


 9    -1.0
11    0.0
13    1.0
Name: b, dtype: float64 
 9     4
11    5
13    6
Name: b, dtype: int64 ********************


 15   -1.0
17    0.0
19    1.0
Name: c, dtype: float64 
 15    7
17    8
19    9
Name: c, dtype: int64 ********************
```

- Yet, if I make any object-only computations in the transform function, then the Transform flounders in handling this case gracefully and throws an error when the iteration reached a numeric column. Also, here it did not go through a column entirely before moving on to the next column. It decides to exhaust all the columns in the first group and then move on to the next group:

```
g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x.str.cat(x),'*'*20))
output:

 3    A1A1
5    B1B1
7    C1C1
Name: name, dtype: object ********************
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2705229/621028603.py in <module>
----> 1 g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x.str.cat(x),'*'*20))

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in transform(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
   1357 
   1358         if not isinstance(func, str):
-> 1359             return self._transform_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
   1360 
   1361         elif func not in base.transform_kernel_allowlist:

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _transform_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1304             # Try slow path and fast path.
   1305             try:
-> 1306                 path, res = self._choose_path(fast_path, slow_path, group)
   1307             except TypeError:
   1308                 return self._transform_item_by_item(obj, fast_path)

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _choose_path(self, fast_path, slow_path, group)
   1415     def _choose_path(self, fast_path: Callable, slow_path: Callable, group: DataFrame):
   1416         path = slow_path
-> 1417         res = slow_path(group)
   1418 
   1419         # if we make it here, test if we can use the fast path

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in <lambda>(group)
   1408         else:
   1409             fast_path = lambda group: func(group, *args, **kwargs)
-> 1410             slow_path = lambda group: group.apply(
   1411                 lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis
   1412             )

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in <lambda>(x)
   1409             fast_path = lambda group: func(group, *args, **kwargs)
   1410             slow_path = lambda group: group.apply(
-> 1411                 lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs), axis=self.axis
   1412             )
   1413         return fast_path, slow_path

/tmp/ipykernel_2705229/621028603.py in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 g.transform(lambda x: print('\n'*2,x.str.cat(x),'*'*20))

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5459             or name in self._accessors
   5460         ):
-> 5461             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5462         else:
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    178             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    179             return self._accessor
--> 180         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    181         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    182         # https://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py in __init__(self, data)
    152         from pandas.core.arrays.string_ import StringDtype
    153 
--> 154         self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
    155         self._is_categorical = is_categorical_dtype(data.dtype)
    156         self._is_string = isinstance(data.dtype, StringDtype)

~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py in _validate(data)
    215 
    216         if inferred_dtype not in allowed_types:
--> 217             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
    218         return inferred_dtype
    219 

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I am not able to form a cohesive understanding of how the transform works in pandas. Can you please help me understand what the under-the-hood universe of pandas groupby transform functionality is?

Comment: it's pretty simple,  if calls the function for each series (column) in the group.  if you use pandas 1.3.1 you get `<ipython-input-124-3ae075a73148>:15: FutureWarning:

Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.transform is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .transform, select only columns which should be valid for the transforming function.
`. i.e. your example of `mean()` will become an error which for me is more expected behaviour

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Good to know it is pretty simple. You have answered the ambiguity I was facing in the mean() case. Can you please also explain the other queries I have raised? Such as In the first case (just a vanilla print) where the entire group (not just the series) is also iterated over or, the last case (concatenation example) where instead of going through the entire series the iteration jumps to the first group of another column. Can you shed some light on the order in which the Transform is deciding to iterate?

Comment: I've also ran into this. Created an bugreport. Upvote/comment, plz. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44977